# Windows Server 2008 sp2 installation is hung

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I'm currently installing SP2 on my Windows Server 2008 server. The installation program has been running for 2 hours now. There is no CPU activity. I think it is hung. The latest event log entry of source "Servicing" is from 2 hours ago. It says:

"Windows Servicing completed the process of changing update 948465-131_en-us_GDR from package KB948465 (Service Pack) into Resolving(Resolving) state"

Is there a log file I can look at to see if it is still active?
Otherwise, can I safely cancel the Installation program? Or should I reboot the server and try the instllation again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This server has SQL Server 2005 installed. Earlier, when I first saw SP2 was hung, I stopped the SQL Server service. But I did not stop the other sql services.

Now I have just stopped all sql related services. The installation completed 2 minutes later. I really don't know what it was waiting for. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

2 hours is too long. Try to cancel out. If it doesn't, reboot and try it again. Hopefully you made a backup of the System State before the SP installation in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts:

- Does your server have any abnormal configurations?
- Try [following this guide](http://dotnetwizard.net/vista-stuff/installing-vista-service-pack-2-sp2-kb948465/)
- Maybe you don't have enough free disk space?
- Try re downloading the SP2 update and running an MD5 check on it

Always make sure you leave yourself a way out if things go pear shaped.

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble with Windows 2008 R2 server before.  Sometimes, in my experience the Windows Update freezes up, especially on a fresh install of 2008.   The workaround I discovered, is to apply just a few patches at a time and reboot between each one.   Using that method, I eventually was able to patch a machine with all required updates.